# Can't open InputStream on Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE result

Tags: android, kotlin, inputstream

So, I wan't to make a simple recording app in which a user can select their preferred save location.
I plan on getting the Uri of the selected dir via Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, save and process it with InputStream and MediaRecorder.

When I try to process the Result in my onActivityResult,

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == resources.getInteger(R.integer.request_code_preference_storage) &&
                resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            val uri = data!!.data
            val inputstream = InputStreamHelper.readTextFromUri(uri!!, context!!)
    }
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:Download flg=0xc3 }} to activity {de.ur.mi.audidroid/de.ur.mi.audidroid.views.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload

I don't know why it won't take the uri. DocumentFile will take it without any complaints through `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context!!,uri!!)`.

The InputStreamHelper is an object I basically copied directly from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory).

```
object InputStreamHelper{
fun readTextFromUri(uri: Uri, context: Context): String {
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
        BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use { reader ->
            var line: String? = reader.readLine()
            while (line != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line)
                line = reader.readLine()
            }
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString()
}
}
```

I'm confused and confounded. It's nothing complicated but I hit a roadblock.

Answer (score 1):

If you used `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, that allows the user to pick a document *tree*, representing a collection of content. You cannot open an `InputStream` on that.

Perhaps you should be using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. This allows the user to pick an individual piece of content, and you can open an `InputStream` on that.

BTW, I think that you could replace that loop construct with:

```
return context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { it.reader().readLines() }
```